# laravel access array data of other table with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

To explain the relationship between my models as abstract as possible, I have four tables, Users, Table1,Table2 and Table3.

Table1 has property: id,Table2_id,user_id.
Table2 has property: id and other properties
Table3 has property: id, Table2_id, amount.

In Table3, amount property is inserted as array. I want to retrieve the amount property with relationship, so I tried using  `$details = auth()->user()->table1()->with(['table2.table3','user'])->get();`. In my view, I use `@foreach($details as $detail){{$detail->table2->table3->amount }}@endforeach` to retrieve the amount value. But I got this error `Trying to get property 'amount' of non-object`.

So how to actually get all the array amount property values?

Comment: You said it is an array but you are accessing it as an object.  Did you tried `$detail->table2->table3['amount']` ?

Comment: @danish-khan-I it shows blank at the area where i want it to print